# Cursor not moving when key pressed second time

Tags: c++, cursor

Hey I have a c++ code in visual studio 2013. 
I want to move the cursor up down left right. but the problem it's not moving when i press the same key second time.

Thanks in advance
Here's my code

```
do
{
    // Get user input (non-blocking) if it exists
    WORD wKeyCode = GetKey();

    // Process input to update application state
    switch(wKeyCode)
    {
    case VK_ESCAPE:
        bExit = true;
    case VK_LEFT:
        if(X >= 0 && X < MAP_WIDTH){
            gotoxy(X - 1, Y);
        }
        break;

    case VK_RIGHT:
        if(X >= 0 && X < MAP_WIDTH){
            gotoxy(X + 1, Y);
        }
        break;
    case VK_UP:
        if(Y >= 0 && Y < MAP_HEIGHT){
            gotoxy(X, Y - 1);
        }
        break;
    case VK_DOWN:
        if(Y >= 0 && Y < MAP_HEIGHT){
            gotoxy(X, Y + 1);
        }
        break;
    case VK_SPACE:
        if(tileMap[X][Y] == WALL){
            tileMap[X][Y] = EMPTY;
        }
        else if(tileMap[X][Y] == EMPTY){
            tileMap[X][Y] = WALL;
        }
        break;
    };
```

and the goto function

```
void gotoxy(int X, int Y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = X;
    coord.Y = Y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(
        GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `X` and `Y` variables in each case the same way you pass them to `qotoxy`, (or just do it in `gotoxy` if they are global). You need to keep track of the cursor's position if you want to make relative movements.

Example for `case VK_LEFT`:

```
if(X >= 0 && X < MAP_WIDTH) {
    gotoxy(X - 1, Y);
    X = X - 1; // or --X;
}
```

A minimalistic version:

```
if(X >= 0 && X < MAP_WIDTH) {
    gotoxy(--X, Y);
}
```

Comment: Im sorry I dont get it. Could you please explain it via code. just paste the few lines I should change

Comment: @Munaem Rudab Provided an example.

Comment: Hey I tried that now it's giving me an error at X++ . I tried X=X+1 too but it's still not working. DO yu have any idea how to increment a variable in C++ visual studio?

Comment: Done. Thank you so mch :)